# Display recently added products on 404 page

Tags: 404, content

Is it ok to display recently added products on 404 page?

What are the best practices? Does Google like it?

Sure the main message would be "Page not found".

Comment: It's perfectly acceptable. A page that returns a header status of 404 will not be factored into rankings since Google only factors indexable pages. 410 Gone and 404 Error are not indexable.

Answer (score 1):

Totally possible: Go to cPanel and edit the Error pages. For every server error type, you can add HTML code. Regarding Google, error pages are not indexed so I see no evil from Google's side.

Comment: The OP didn't mention using cPanel, but the same is applicable for other control panels and error pages in general.